# MySQLi prepared statements displaying error because of MySQLnd not installed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using this code to run a select statement in MySQLi

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE forename = ? and surname = ? ');
$stmt->bind_param('vv', $forename, $surname);

$foremame = "Forename";
$surname = "Surname";

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["sequence"];
}
$stmt -> close();
$mysqli -> close();
```

But I am getting a fatal error saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

Because I do not have MySQLnd installed but I cannot install it as I am using a shared web server and the host will not install it.

How can I use a MySQLi prepared statement without having to have MySQLnd installed as I want to prevent SQL injection attacks

Comment: Everyone on SO keeps telling me to Not use MySQL as it's deprecated so I try to learn something new and no one helps. I cannot find anything on the internet about it either as I just get the same errors

Comment: Even if you would use PDO, you will eventually end up having the same dependencies. You might aswel get new hosting, where you *can* choose your dependencies ;)

Comment: @charliejsford You're probably just in bad luck. There's nothing wrong with MySQL for simple Web Development. As they say *Haters gonna hate*. It's just personal flavor. Only in certain "extremer" situations it might be actually critical to choose to not use MySQL. Don't hesitate to use it!

Comment: @Jessica Why can't he? Prepared statements don't require the ND driver.

Comment: @Barmar You're right - I don't know why he thinks he needs ND then. He needs MySQLi but the fact stands that he has no control over his environment, and you cannot use a library like that without it being installed. That was the point.

Comment: @Jessica He needs ND for `get_result()`, which allows you to use `fetch_assoc()` with prepared statements. Without ND you have to use `bind_result()`, as in my answer.

Comment: Well there you go. Glad that was cleared up ;) BTW @charliejsford You should try setting up a local environment like WAMP so you can use whatever tools you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$stmt->bind_result()` to bind the results to variables, then `$stmt->fetch()` to fetch the results into the bound variables.

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($var1, $var2, $var3, ...); // Use more meaningful variable names

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $var3; // to get the third column in the results
}
```

I strongly recommend listing the colum names explicitly in the `SELECT` clause, rather than `*`, since this method of accessing the results is dependent on the specific order of the columns.

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: I've added an example. But isn't the documentation the first place you look when you're new to something? If not, it should be.

Comment: Is there a generic function that can be used where you don't need to specify the `$var1, $var2...`?

Comment: @luke If you have the `MYSQLND` driver, you can use `$stmt->fetch_assoc()` to get an associative array after executing a prepared statement.