# mysqli:get_result functionality without mysqlnd and with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

As described in the title, I cannot install mysqlnd on my host, but I want to keep using prepared statements. For ease of coding, on my development machine, I used this method:

```
    public function qry( $query, $params = null ){
    if ( is_array( $params ) ){
        if ( substr_count( $query, "?") != count($params) ){
            error("Parameters amount does not match query!");
        }

        $types = "";

        foreach( $params as $parameter ) {

            $t = substr( gettype( $parameter ), 0, 1 );

            if ( in_array( $t , array( "i", "s", "d" ) ) ){
                $types .= $t;
            } else {
                error( "Invalid parameter type: $t !" );
            }

        }

    }

    $q = $this -> dbc -> prepare( $query );

    if ( $q === false ){
        error( "Error in SQL statement: " . $this -> dbc -> error  );
    }

    if ( $params ){
        call_user_func_array( array( $q,  "bind_param" ) , array_merge( array( $types ), refValues( $params ) ) );
    }

    $q -> execute();

    return $q -> get_result();
}
```

How would I go about returning the same or similiar resultset without get_result?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848626/mysqli-prepared-statements-displaying-error-because-of-mysqlnd-not-installed?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the project and using PDO